# jQuery .find() on HTML string in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm working with [bootbox](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox) in IE8 and am having issues with the source [right here](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/blob/master/bootbox.js#L583-L585).

In Chrome or an modern browser, the lines with `.find()` correctly find the child elements from the `dialog` element generated from the HTML string. In IE8 these return undefined and results in the rest of the markup not being put together correctly and no modal being displayed.

I've seen some issues with IE8 regarding doing this with custom elements, but there's nothing custom about the template being parsed. This is from the bootbox source:

```
"<div class='bootbox modal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog'>" +
    "<div class='modal-dialog'>" +
        "<div class='modal-content'>" +
            "<div class='modal-body'><div class='bootbox-body'></div></div>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
"</div>"
```

I've tried removing the `tabindex` and `role` attributes as well, to no avail.

My jQuery version is v1.11.2, and current version of bootbox.

For reference, I've also [opened an issue on the bootbox GitHub page](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/366), but would love to be able to solve this and submit a PR. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery 1.x?  Since jQuery 2.x dropped support for IE8.

Comment: @Yetti99 positive :)

`>>$.fn.jquery` returns `"1.11.2"`

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and see what `dialog` holds?

Comment: where's a demo that replicates problem? hard to post about bugs (here or in repo) and not have a way to replicate. Have used jQuery going back to IE6 and never seen a problem with `find()` on valid html or xml

Comment: @epascarello yes, it has the element (length of 1), but the `children` property is empty.

Comment: also should check bootstrap docs as I think they dropped IE8 support, or you may need polyfills for some of their methods

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately, jsbin and jsfiddle both don't work in IE8. Re: bootstrap support -- their website suggests they support 8+.

Comment: @sethetter You can build the fiddle in any browser, and then test `<fiddle-url>/show` in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely caused by invalid HTML in your code. different browsers treat invalid code differently. To fix this issue validate your code with http://validator.w3.org first

Comment: Running the markup that is generated through the validator suggests it's valid. Since this markup is attempting to be built before interacting with the actual document, I assume nothing else on the page is interfering.

Comment: Is there any HTML5 elements or code that might be "invalid" for IE8?

Comment: Not that I can see. It's all div's, as you can see above. Also, I'm including the html5shiv on the page which should take care of those issues if there were any.

Comment: @sethetter Please create a fiddle to repro the issue. Build it in a different browser if you need to, and test in IE8.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'm working on that now. With just loading jQuery it seems to work fine. Loading bootbox and bootstrap seems to also work. So now I'm trying to isolate what in my code would cause the jQuery `find` method to not work properly in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the code causing the issue was an IE8 polyfill provided by another library -> https://github.com/bootstrap-wysiwyg/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/blob/master/dist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.js#L6-L20

By removing this polyfill and replacing with something that was a temporary workaround for this particular issue, the problem was resolved.